# Create your own certificate - "The Manifest Designer could not import the certificate"

Tags: certificate, windows-8.1, packaging, appx

I want to create certificate to signing my application:

```
c:\certcenter> makecert -sv demas.me.pvk -n "cn=demas.me" demas.me.cert -b 01/01/2014 -e 01/01/2015 -r
Succeeded

c:\certcenter> pvk2pfx.exe -pvk demas.me.pvk -spc demas.me.cert -pfx demas.me.pfx
```

When I am trying to select certificate in VS I get error message: "The Manifest Designer could not import the certificate".

Here is Publisher, Publisher name in the appmanifest and error message:

[image]

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Change the expiry date to be in the past and see if that alters the error returned. Might help.

Comment: No, I have the same error.   I have added this certificate to Trusted Publishers, but didn't help too.

Comment: Could be an issue with the private key. Use OpenSSL to check it and the created certificate is valid. Openssl will give you better error messages.

Comment: I have opened "Manage Computer Certificates", find my certificate and in the properties I have found "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate".  Can you provide a link, how can I use OpenSSL to check certificate ?

Comment: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html

Comment: Which of three files do I need to check (cert, pvk, pfx).  I use 'openssl.exe x509 -in c:\certcenter\demas.me.cert -text -noout' and get error message: 3888:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE.  The same with other three files.

Comment: I have this error on both computers:  Windows and Mac, so I think the reason is not openssl installation.

Comment: What format is your certificates? PEM PKCS12? If you open then in a text editor do you see text or binary? If openssl cannot parse your certs or keys then probably nothing else will.

Comment: Did you find the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Step by step, instructions for one that can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/desktop/appxpkg/how-to-create-a-package-signing-certificate
and essentially are:

`MakeCert /n publisherName /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /e 
expirationDate /sv MyKey.pvk MyKey.cer`

`Pvk2Pfx /pvk MyKey.pvk /pi pvkPassword /spc MyKey.cer /pfx MyKey.pfx [/po pfxPassword]`

The options passed in to `MakeCert` are explained in the page, but here's an excerpt:

> `/r` Creates a self-signed root certificate. This simplifies management for your test certificate.
>
> `/h 0` Marks the basic constraint for the certificate as an end-entity. This prevents the certificate from being used as a Certification Authority (CA) that can issue other certificates.
>
> `/eku` Sets the Enhanced Key Usage (EKU) values for the certificate.
>
> `/e`  Sets the expiration date of the certificate.
>
> (...)

---

Update:

Please be aware that when using MakeCert with expiration and start dates it uses the format of mm/dd/yyyy so 12/09/2018 is the 9th of December 2018, *not* the 12th of September 2018.